# How to transpile Javascript Function to PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I have this function:

```
function fix(str){
    return str.replace(/(\d+)(\.\d+)?/g, function (_, h, m) { 
        return ('0'+h).substr(-2) + ':' + ('0' + (Math.floor(m*60) || 0)).substr(-2) + 'hs';
    });
}
```

which I'd like to transpile to PHP, but I don't know how since I can't pass a function to `preg_replace` in PHP. How can I do this?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

Comment: Oh thanks I didn't know the function!

Comment: BTW answer it if you want so that I can accept it later

Comment: Rethink your logic on this process. Why are you doing this in the first place?

Comment: This function takes a string like this: `8.25 - 18.5` and converts it into a readable time, like this: `08:15 - 18:30hs`. Before I did this in JS but because of how my filtering system works I need it done on the server.